# Background glitches after turning on tearfree [intel graphics]

Tags: intel-graphics, configuration

[example of glitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YznH.png)

After trying to get rid of screen tearing I reset my computer and found some weird boxes on my background

in /etc/X11/xorg.conf I added `Option      "TearFree"    "true"`

Comment: I tried restarting but that made things worse where frames weren't refreshed. Had to just remove xorg.conf

Comment: it did! Thank you!

Comment: If the duplicate link in the 2nd comment answered your question, you can mark your question as a duplicate by clicking the link that is located near the outside of the text box of your question.